Does the phrase "a further few" sound natural to you? E.g.: "A further few volunteers were needed."
The textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language" (CGEL), page 353:
(1) A further few volunteers were needed.
Since the phrase "a further few" is one which doesn't occur on forums for learning English (based on search results on these forums: 1, 2, 3), this makes me doubt whether I can use it or not. So I have the question:
Does "a further few" sound natural to you?

'A few more' sounds better and is very much more likely to be heard.

It sounds stodgy to me. Maybe it was common in the past, but not now.

@Barmar - Actually, this shows that usage has increased since 1900. I agree that 'A further three' (or any number) sounds more natural.

an additional n [units] and a few additional have pretty much ousted that construction.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+further+few%2Ca+few+additional&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-US&smoothing=3

Your example uses: a further few volunteers, and not just a further few. What does CGEL say about that sentence? You really should tell us.

As I've noted before,  Be careful of CGEL examples.  They are chosen to illustrate edge cases, not to illustrate typical English.

It's grammatically correct. 'Further' is a determiner modifying 'few' which is a quantifier. It doesn't sound unnatural, just very formal - as has been pointed out in a comment, the more natural, conversational option would be "a few more". However, "a further few" may well be more appropriate as part of a process or narrative sequence, because the word "further" inherently suggests progression, continuation, or an additional step in an ongoing series.

Ludwig guru [you have to sign up]
Parties are restricted by law to spending only 40p ($0.75) per voter in each constituency (plus, for each candidate, another £7,150 and a further few pence per voter).  The Economist
The best writing reference in the English language.
Many other examples with time periods: months, years, weeks

That quote must be ancient, $0.40 is around $0.50 these days.

@MichaelHarvey So what? Who cares? That does not discredit the usage. Make sure not to upvote me, though.
